# Check remote file availability with AIR

Tags: apache-flex, air

I was wondering if there's a remote file availability check using Flex-AIR. Not a local file.

Example: For displaying a image place holder instead of a broken image icon.

```
image.source = imageUrl + "/__default.gif";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for the ioError and httpStatus events.

1. `ioError` - "Dispatched when an input/output error occurs."
2. `httpStatus` - "Dispatched when a network request is made over HTTP and Flash Player or AIR can detect the HTTP status code."

[Source: Flex AS3 Doc]

Also, the HTTP Status can be:

1xx - Informational;
2xx - Success;
3xx - Redirection;
4xx - Client Error;
5xx - Server Error;

*) xx is a number made out of two digits (e.g. 404 or 200).

Comment: I guess you suggest me that every time I want to check if the file is available, I need to do a URLRequest and evaluate it's results?

Comment: Pretty much. URLRequest if that's how you want to load the file.

Comment: I can't believe this is the only way, what if I have hundreds of images in a single page catalog?

Comment: When you load an image externally it will throw an IO Error Exception anyway, you might as well listen for it if it happens and act accordingly.